# can Firebreath detect the plugin object's 'width' and 'height' change?

Tags: c++, npapi, firebreath

can Firebreath detect the plugin object's 'width' and 'height' change as event, can it?

If no, does that mean I need to periodically check if the plugin object's width and height change. Then inside plugin, I modified my child window size? Does the parent window size even change following the object's width and height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things differ a little bit depending on what platform you're on, but generally you'll get a ResizedEvent from FireBreath (through your PluginWindow) whenever it's resized.  The browser takes care of resizing.

If you're using windowless on windows or any mac drawing platform then you'll only be drawing in response to a RefreshEvent (or derivative) and you can get the width and height from the PluginWindow at that time.

Comment: i should slap myself haha. Should had spent more time on the header files of firebreath. Just notice the RefreshEvent but not the ResizedEvent. Got it working. Thank. Basically, from the event, grap the new plugin window size, set it to child window using SetWindowPos, then my update all my SDL_Window parameters (include renderer, and texture). Both my plugin (video application) window and object width/height are matched now even resized.